# Socket Programming res.sendFile is not a function

Tags: express, websocket

res.sendFile is not a function.

The following is my server js code

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var users = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

app.listen(3000)

io.on("connection", function (client) {
    client.on("join", function (name) {
        users[client.id] = name;
        client.emit("update", "Connected to Server");
        socket.sockets.emit("update", name + " has entered the confession room");
        socket.sockets.emit("update-users", users);
    });

    client.on("send", function (msg) {
        socket.sockets.emit("chat", users[client.id], msg);
    });

    client.on("disconnect", function () {
        socket.sockets.emit("update", users[client.id] + " has left the confession room");
        delete users[client.id];
        socket.sockets.emit("update-users", users);
    });
});
```

Things I have tried:
- Checking the order of the parameter.
- Installing express module.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate servers with these two lines of code and you're passing the one to socket.io that you never start:

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);    // one on port 80

app.listen(3000);                          // one on port 3000
```

Remove the first one, then modify your code as shown below.  And, make sure you're connecting on port 3000 where the Express server and socket.io severs are.

Or, if you want the server and socket.io to be on port 80, then change to:

```
const server = app.listen(80);
```

So, you should end up with this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');
const users = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

// various socket.io code here
```

Comment: @kokkei - Where'd you go? I provided an answer to your question 16 hours ago and no response. Stack overflow is far less useful when you attempt to use it that way. It's works a lot better for all involved if you respond timely to answers that are provided shortly after you posted.  Otherwise, people just see a non-responsive author and decide to go suspend their time helping people who do respond.